# Python / JSON: Loop themoviedb api image call

Tags: python, json

So I'm about to start at this again. It bugged me yesterday for hours so I thought I'd best ask you lovely lot for a little helping hand.

I have a .txt file with a list of image ID's

```
tt1211837
tt0151804
tt2543164
tt2911666
tt2140479
```

I can't seem to get it to loop through the lines using the ID as

```
tmdb_posters('ID')
```

Here is the code without a loop (which works great on it's own).

```
import os
import requests
import random


CONFIG_PATTERN = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/configuration?api_key={key}'
IMG_PATTERN = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{imdbid}/images?api_key={key}'
KEY = '*****'

def _get_json(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.json()

def get_poster_urls(imdbid):

    config = _get_json(CONFIG_PATTERN.format(key=KEY))
    base_url = config['images']['base_url']
    sizes = config['images']['poster_sizes']

    def size_str_to_int(x):
        return float("inf") if x == 'original' else int(x[1:])
    max_size = max(sizes, key=size_str_to_int)

    posters = _get_json(IMG_PATTERN.format(key=KEY,imdbid=imdbid))['posters']
    poster_urls = []
    for poster in posters:
        rel_path = poster['file_path']
        url = "{0}{1}{2}".format(base_url, max_size, rel_path)
        poster_urls.append(url)

    return poster_urls


def tmdb_posters(imdbid, count=None, outpath='.'):
    urls = get_poster_urls(imdbid)
    print random.choice(urls)

if __name__=="__main__":
      tmdb_posters('tt1211837') # <--- ID
```

But when I try and put this into ANY form of loop I get a 400 Client Error and another telling me that the json key 'posters' is bad.

Many thanks if you can help in advance. I'd like to keep my hair.

UPDATE

```
import urllib
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import time
import requests
import random

CONFIG_PATTERN = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/configuration?api_key={key}'
IMG_PATTERN = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{imdbid}/images?api_key={key}'
KEY = '*****'


def _get_json(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.json()


def get_poster_urls(imdbid):

    config = _get_json(CONFIG_PATTERN.format(key=KEY))
    base_url = config['images']['base_url']
    sizes = config['images']['poster_sizes']

    def size_str_to_int(x):
        return float("inf") if x == 'original' else int(x[1:])
    max_size = max(sizes, key=size_str_to_int)

    posters = _get_json(IMG_PATTERN.format(key=KEY, imdbid=imdbid))['posters']
    poster_urls = []
    for poster in posters:
        rel_path = poster['file_path']
        url = "{0}{1}{2}".format(base_url, max_size, rel_path)
        poster_urls.append(url)

    return poster_urls


def tmdb_posters(imdbid, count=None, outpath='.'):
    urls = get_poster_urls(imdbid)
    print random.choice(urls)




file = open("data/titles3.txt", "r")

splits = file.read().splitlines()
for line in splits:
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        file = open("data/posters.txt", "a")
        woop = tmdb_posters(line)
        file.write(str(woop))
        file.close()
```

UPDATE 2

```
import urllib
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import time
import requests
import random

CONFIG_PATTERN = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/configuration?api_key={key}'
IMG_PATTERN = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{imdbid}/images?api_key={key}'
KEY = '*****'


def _get_json(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.json()


def get_poster_urls(imdbid):

    config = _get_json(CONFIG_PATTERN.format(key=KEY))
    base_url = config['images']['base_url']
    sizes = config['images']['poster_sizes']

    def size_str_to_int(x):
        return float("inf") if x == 'original' else int(x[1:])
    max_size = max(sizes, key=size_str_to_int)

    posters = _get_json(IMG_PATTERN.format(key=KEY, imdbid=imdbid))['posters']
    poster_urls = []
    for poster in posters:
        rel_path = poster['file_path']
        url = "{0}{1}{2}".format(base_url, max_size, rel_path)
        poster_urls.append(url)

    return poster_urls


def tmdb_posters(imdbid, count=None, outpath='.'):
    urls = get_poster_urls(imdbid)
    print random.choice(urls)


with open('data/titles3.txt', 'r') as ids:
        ids = ids.read().split('\n')
        for poster in ids:
            if __name__ == "__main__":
                file = open("data/posters.txt", "a")
                file.write(str(tmdb_posters(poster)) + "\n")
                file.close()
```

SUSSED IT

```
import urllib
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import time
import requests
import random

CONFIG_PATTERN = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/configuration?api_key={key}'
IMG_PATTERN = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{imdbid}/images?api_key={key}'
KEY = '*****'


def _get_json(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.json()


def get_poster_urls(imdbid):

    config = _get_json(CONFIG_PATTERN.format(key=KEY))
    base_url = config['images']['base_url']
    sizes = config['images']['poster_sizes']

    def size_str_to_int(x):
        return float("inf") if x == 'original' else int(x[1:])
    max_size = max(sizes, key=size_str_to_int)

    posters = _get_json(IMG_PATTERN.format(key=KEY, imdbid=imdbid))['posters']
    poster_urls = []
    for poster in posters:
        rel_path = poster['file_path']
        url = "{0}{1}{2}".format(base_url, max_size, rel_path)
        poster_urls.append(url)

    return poster_urls


def tmdb_posters(imdbid, count=None, outpath='.'):
    urls = get_poster_urls(imdbid)
    woop  = random.choice(urls)
    file = open("data/posters.txt", "a")
    file.write(str(woop) + "\n")
    file.close()


with open('data/titles3.txt', 'r') as ids:
        ids = ids.read().split('\n')
        for poster in ids:
            if __name__ == "__main__":
                tmdb_posters(poster)
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment yet,but it seems to be working just fine in a for loop.
Can you post the code , how you read the ids

Comment: I tried a few ways yesterday but here is one I dug out. Not too sure I'm getting it right though.

file = open("data/titles3.txt", "r")

for line in file:
    if __name__=="__main__":
          print tmdb_posters(line)

Comment: there will be a newline character('\n') added at the end of each line, so you need to remove it

Comment: That does seem logical.

Comment: Try this,

with open('t.txt' ,'r') as ids:
    ids = ids.read().split('\n')

print(ids)

Comment: `file = open("data/titles3.txt", "r")

splits = file.read().splitlines()
for line in splits:
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        tmdb_posters(line)`

Comment: Now I just need to get it into a new txt file.

Comment: it is now saving in a new line?

Comment: Yup. But it's writing 'None' to each line and outputting the urls. I'm baffled now. Another bash in the question up top.

Comment: Change to this and check

```with open('data/titles3.txt', 'r') as ids:
        ids = ids.read().split('\n')
        for poster in ids:
            if __name__ == "__main__":
                with open("data/posters.txt", "a+") as file 
                    file.write(str(tmdb_posters(poster)) + "\n")
```